# Web browser (Chrome and firefox) is able to connect with ganache but not able to connect with local ethereum (geth)node

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, mist, ganache

Firefox browser is able to connect with ganache and I am able to execute DAPP using browser. However, I am not able to connect with local geth client using web browser. Geth node is all ready up same as ganache. I am getting following error message on firefox -

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

Comment: are you using --rpccorsdomain flag when running Geth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `--rpccorsdomain "*"` flag while starting `geth` node. See [This answer to understand importance of --rpccorsdomain flag](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3306/37751)